# how to return a model with specific category

Tags: laravel

I have a model that can have more then one category, relationship is defined like this:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(ListCategory::class, 'listing_listcategory', 'listing_id', 'category_id');
}
```

and inside category model I have:

```
public function listings()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Listing::class, 'listing_listcategory');
}
```

How can I select only models that belong to one category?

Currently I have this:

```
Listing::closest($lat, $lng, $radius)->orderBy('distance');
```

Which returns closest models based on location, how do I return only models with specific category?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method:

```
Listing::closest($lat, $lng, $radius)
       ->whereHas('categories', function($q) use($categoryId) {
           $q->where('id', $categoryId);
       })
       ->orderBy('distance')
       ->get();
```